# Word 2010 automatically create a list of definitions

Tags: microsoft-word

I am currently writing my master thesis, and in this thesis I present a lot of definitions and theorems. Throughout the whole master thesis I reference to these definitions and theorems a lot, so I wanted to create an appendix that lists all definitions and theorems I present. Doing this manually is a lot of work, so my question is if it is possible to do this in an automated way using Word 2010. I searched a bit, but I could not find anything that does what I want.

What I want to achieve is the following:

- Automatic numbering of definitions/theorems based on the chapter/section in which it is presented
- Generate an overview of all definitions/theorems presented in the document, which includes the title, number and text of the definitions/theorems
- References to definitions/theorems in the text, that automatically update if the numbering of definitions/theorems changes when new ones are added or existing ones deleted

If this is not possible, is it at least possible to create a listing of the numbers/titles of the definitions/theorems and the page at which they can be found?

Any tips or links are appreciated!

Comment: A custom style using a numbered list should do the trick. But it may be quirky if it gets too big. You could consider switching to LaTeX if you have the time.

Comment: Does a custom style using a numbered list allow numbering based on the section it is in? As an example, if I want to add some definitions/theorems to section 2.2, I would like the numbering to start at 2.2.1 and continue with 2.2.2, etc. And for a section 3.3 the numbering should look like 3.3.1, 3.3.2, etc.

Comment: I found the solution myself, but I cannot answer my own question right now, because I am a new user.

An easy solution is to make use of captions and cross references. For a caption type you can assign a numbering that is based on the headings of the chapter you add the caption to. This can be found in the References tab of the ribbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment on the question:

An easy solution is to make use of captions and cross references. For a caption type you can assign a numbering that is based on the headings of the chapter you add the caption to. This can be found in the References tab of the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you could use the Index feature in Word:

HIGHLIGHT: The text you want to appear in your appendix.

CLICK: (On the top ribbon) References

CLICK: Mark Entry

CLICK: Mark

CLICK: Close

You'll see an XE code that looks like this {XE"text you highlighted"}.

Go to: Wherever you want to create your appendix

CLICK: On that page

CLICK: Insert index

Your text should appear on this page.

You can continue to mark text throughout your document. Go back to your index/appendix anytime and CLICK within it.

CLICK: Update index

Notes:

You can choose default index styles, and you can add any heading you want.. in your case "Appendix 1" or whatever.

You can work with the index manually, but all changes will disappear when you Update.

To update the index, CLICK within it then CLICK: Update Index

To show or hide the xe codes CLICK: ¶ in the Home ribbon

The index/appendix does not update automatically. You need to update as above.

Finally, a caution: Save your document as "Document name with xe codes" or something so you keep your original document without them. As with many Word tools, this one has a tendency to sometime go wacky and mess everything up, with no way to restore the original (that I know of). If that happens, it'll be kind of nice to have the original, uncorrupted version of your years of hard work!